# Why was my answer to my questions deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, specific-answer

To my big surprise my answer [to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483503/most-mature-asp-net-mvc-blog-engine) got deleted.

I checked the FAQ. My answer "Orchad" fundamentally answers the question. It's not a "commentary". It's not asking another question. It's not a "Thanks" response. It's not an exact duplicate. It's not barely a link and it's a complete answer.

So why did it get deleted?

**Update**:
For the downvoters, read my comments.

Comment: Now a days we are very much strict in quality Q & A, so such type of posts are getting deleted.

Comment: The whole question is really not constructive and not answerable in a non disputable way. This should not have been asked on SO.

Comment: What do you mean `"It's not barely a link"` ? Isn't it a link only answer ?

Comment: You didn't even add one word of description: what's this site? Why is it good?

Comment: As I see it, that question is dated and not useful....can we take the shortcut and delete the whole question?

Comment: This question confuses me almost as much as one of your earlier Meta questions did at the time. What do you mean by *"It's not barely a link and it's a complete answer."*? Because I'd say, it's a link and not an answer.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I was wondering. I hesitated to vote to delete but I choose not to as I'm not competent on the domain enough to tell if the answers still hold water. If they're still good and relevant, as they're upvoted, maybe there's no need to be in a hurry to delete it.

Comment: @dystroy: The answers are from two years ago and basically are "there are only few...and I'm writing my own right now". I don't think that this is correct anymore, and especially not useful.

Comment: @dystroy There's a difference between a text which is also a link and  just a url. When you look at the answer, do you see a url or do you see the name of a CMS!? The link is not visible. A link only answer is like "blahblah.com/orchard/homepage"

Comment: @M. Night Demonbobby Sure.. go delete it and make sure you also delete the 15% of SO questions which are outdated.

Comment: @Sha Follow the link. It's just one mouse click away if you're really curious. When the question is "which CMS.. ", logically the word must be the name of a CMS and not an ice cream flavor.

Comment: @Bar See my answer to destroy & Sha. Are you really that confused!? Give me a break!

Comment: A link-only answer does not have to be a bare URL. What you wrote qualifies as a link-only answer. Those will be deleted.

Comment: @Tony Stack Overflow is meant to be repository for content, not place to host external links. When one arrives to a question page, he's expecting to see actual answers not just "click here to see the answer". Links are all good, but add at least *something*. I neglected to downvote this but now that you wrote "For the downvoters, read my comments" I read the comments. I don't agree with your idea that link only answers are acceptable, hence adding my own downvote.

Comment: @sha Downvote as much as you like as if downvotes hurt me. Look at my question history here and you'll notice most of questions are downvoted a lot. I don't give a hoot. I use meta to say what sucks about SO and why some people don't think straight. If people want to go by the SO book word for word, that's fine. My idea is those are stiff robotic people. If you really think a one word answer does more harm than good, that's your opinion and in my opinion that BS. Everything boils to one thing, was the answer useful or harmful. Some points in the FAQ are idiotic in my opinion.

Comment: OK, let's agree to disagree. I'll keep flagging and deleting myself if possible link only answers, you can post as many as you like.

Comment: and For God's sake, if the answer was too short, edit it. Don't delete it. What good does one do when one deletes a 16+ upvoted answer!? Obviously a lot of people liked it enough. What can I say, Lots of BS going on in this world.

Comment: As for editing, that's **your** role (the answer author) not mine.

Comment: One more thing: I am all for short answers with a link. I even [fought to undelete such answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182169/152859). See, it's really not that hard to add some context and by this making the answer whole.

Comment: @sha I never got a notification that my answer got deleted. I received a notice yesterday about someone added a comment and god jolly, the comment was that they didn't agree with the closing reason, which I  agree with. And obviously I am not scanning my old answers to see if any got deleted. FYI, none of the comments for the answer complained about it being short. Instead it got several upvotes and Bill the lizardface decided to delete it. ANYWAY, the whole question is deleted now. Obviously from some who came here and decided to do something. This is my last comment. I said enough.

Comment: Notification for the answer author when it gets deleted is valid point and was suggested already but that's not the issue here. The question was deleted because it doesn't fit Stack Overflow to begin with. And one last thing, the moderator just acted upon flags, it's not like he went hunting. Too bad I can't explain myself any better.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich For how long have you been a user here now? After almost 4 years you can't tell me you're still surprised that a one word link is considered a bad answer. And if you are, now you know.

Answer (score 24):

It was just a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), which is not acceptable as an Answer.

See the deleted answer's screen-shot,

[image]

somebody might have flagged it as a link only answer, that's why it got deleted by a moderator.

If you want to undelete it then just edit your answer with proper description and flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: It's the name of the CMS which is also a link. It's not a url only answer.  Maybe it was a too concise answer. Plus it could have been edited. Not deleted. That was an unnecessary extreme action. The moderator should not blindly take action just because it was flagged. Use proper judgement.

Comment: Interesting symmetry here: -17 for Q, +17 for A. You're 3 votes way from your [fourth gold badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal)!

Comment: I don't care about votes and badges. I was never into this type of gamification. I am not into games and I find myself above this.

Comment: @Tony I wasn't referring to you.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich If you had posted only the url, it would have been a link-only answer. If you had posted only the word without the hyperlink, it would have been a low quality answer. The both combined doesn't improve it much; one word and a link is not an answer of acceptable quality. Editing is used to clarify questions and improve answers, yes, but it isn't used to *create* answers. A single word and a link is not an answer that can be improved upon by someone else. If someone has enough knowledge on the topic to write a complete, high quality answer, they should post their own-why credit you?