# Wondering why what appears to be valid answer got deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4284351/447356) got a quick answer which explained nicely the question at stake and got 11 upvotes in total.

The answer was deleted one hour ago.

Worth to mention the answer contains a link to "more details" but even without it, it's just as valid in my opinion.

Was the answer deleted because of the dead link? In such case why not just remove it or look for alternate link?

Was it deleted because it's "too short"? In such case there can't be any long answer and the question better be closed to prevent others from falling to that trap as already happened.

The answer in its full glory to <10K users:

[image]

Comment: Link only answer and the link is dead.

Comment: @Oded no, it's not link only. The first sentence is full answer: the question is "What's the difference?" and it answers just that. If it was just "see [link here]" then you're right but it's not.. :)

Comment: Just quoting the message from the moderator who deleted the answer...

Comment: @Oded so I'd call that poor judgement call... can't blame the mod considering he got lots of flags to handle but still, I do hope it won't happen again too frequently.

Comment: The poster did it right.  Two+ years and 1700 views later, this is now the reference answer and no longer requires a link.  Don't delete vetted answers please.

Comment: Oops! I misunderstood the quick read I did of the question title when I came across that flag, and did not think the text of the answer was an answer. Mistake on my part! Thanks for catching and reporting it!

Comment: @Oded Incidentally, that was not *my* message, but the message from the user who flagged, I expect.

Comment: @AndrewBarber cheers, like I said before to Oded: "can't blame the mod considering he got lots of flags to handle" - happy to hear you do agree with me. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - of course it is.

Comment: @Andrew [oops I did it again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184060/152859)? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first paragraph seems like it could stand on its own. I removed the line containing the dead link and restored the answer. It's still an answer; just one that doesn't contain a reference link anymore.

FWIW, the answer was deleted in response to a flag calling it a link-only answer, when it really isn't.

Comment: I've been seeing more and more flags for 'not an answer' or 'link only answer' lately where the answers are much like the answer above, and I've been declining some of them, and others marking helpful but doing nothing about them.  It feels like certain flaggers are just *anti-link mostly*, instead of being anti-link *only*.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker that's quite sad... think we can do anything against this?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I've been noticing that, too. Not sure how bad it is, though; NAA flags are odd for me - most are really obvious ("Thanks - works for me!", or "Have you solved this, yet?"), but then the rest of what people mean by 'NAA' takes some parsing. I figure a collection of declines might tend to tweak that around. Maybe..

Comment: My general rule is if you remove all the text which talks about the link, if the URL is all you've really got left mark it as NAA. In this case we've got something redeeming, but I don't think you can blame folks for flagging.