# Upvoted answer to a very specific question deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, undelete-request

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608625/convert-ms-sql-server-database-mdf-file-to-mysql-through-phpmyadmin/8608913#8608913) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608625/convert-ms-sql-server-database-mdf-file-to-mysql-through-phpmyadmin) has been deleted.

This is a very relevant question (with 2 upvotes) and my answer specifically addressed what was asked and I provided a working solution. I suppose that's the reason it was upvoted.

However, it's been deleted by a moderator without a reason. Is there anyway I can find out why it was deleted and can it be undeleted?

Comment: Agreed, hopefully done by mistake.

Comment: The moderator was probably acting on a flag (and I would be curious to know what that flag said).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deleted that answer because it contained a link to a site that has been spammed here a good bit, and I did a url search and wiped many of them. Not all were remotely spam, though, and this one certainly was not. Not sure why I would have mistaken it as such; some such spam posts try to 'look' like legitimate answers, and maybe I missed something as a result.

Anyway, I've restored it, and apologize for the goof!

Comment: Blame the coffee... or the lack of it. Always work! :)